# Using two insert statements for two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use two different insert statements with two different tables such as

```
<?
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (ID,Name,Subject, OrderDate) VALUES ('$ID', '$name', '$status', '$ODate')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Order (ID,Subject, Department, Status, OrderDate, Receive, Notes) VALUES ('$ID', '$status', 'Financial', 'Financial Department', '$ODate', 'NO', 'Notes')");
?>
```

It just works with the first table and does not work with the second table.

Can some one help solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised it even runs considering there is a syntax error.

Comment: Because you are missing a double quote ?

Comment: Mr.Nass. is there a typo above? The double quotes are not completed. How can your code even run in the first place? Furthermore, is your schema for table 1 and table 2 similar ?

Comment: Guys please please please this is just example not the real code that I am using

Comment: To make you HAPPY, this is the code that I am using:
`mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (ID,Name,Subject, OrderDate) VALUES ('$ID', '$name', '$status', '$ODate')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Order (ID,Subject, Department, Status, OrderDate, Receive, Notes) VALUES ('$ID', '$status', 'Financial', 'Financial Department', '$ODate', 'NO', 'Notes')");`

Comment: It's pretty important to provide an example that actually demonstrates the problem, not a mockup of example.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: you really should update your question with the actual code you are using, as well the schema for both the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for errors:

```
<?php
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Customer (ID,Name,Subject, OrderDate) VALUES ('$ID', '$name', '$status', '$ODate')";
if(!mysql_query($query1)) {
  throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO Order (ID,Subject, Department, Status, OrderDate, Receive, Notes) VALUES ('$ID', '$status', 'Financial', 'Financial Department', '$ODate', 'NO', 'Notes')";
if(!mysql_query($query2)) {
  throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}
```

I'm guessing you are getting an error because `Order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and should be escaped accordingly:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `Order` (ID,Subject, Department, Status, OrderDate, Receive, Notes) VALUES ('$ID', '$status', 'Financial', 'Financial Department', '$ODate', 'NO', 'Notes')";
```

---

It also seems to me like you're inserting a fixed value as a primary key - are you sure that's what you want?

---

As I said in the comments, you should stop using `mysql_` functions completely and use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Yes, ID is a primary key in both tables and it has to be the same value for one customer. 
Anyway, I will start learning the PDO and MYSQLi 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to DCoder who helped me to solve the problem and advised me to use PDO and MySQLi.

The problem was with the tabel name `Order`, when I replaced it with a new name, it works fine.

I thought the problem with using two `mysql_query` but it is not. The table name that I used is a reserved word in MySQL.

Thanks